# Why are stock image resources fuzzy in notifications?

Tags: android, android-notifications

Any idea why these media controls appear fuzzy? 
[image: Notifications]

I'm creating the icons so:

```
start = Icon.createWithResource(this, android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);
pause = Icon.createWithResource(this, android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause);
reset = Icon.createWithResource(this, android.R.drawable.ic_media_previous);
finish = Icon.createWithResource(this, R.drawable.ic_media_stop);
```

then creating the various `Notification.Action` instances:

```
public Notification.Action getStartAction() {
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = getPendingIntent(NOTI_START_CLICKED);
    return new Notification.Action.Builder(start, "Start", pendingIntent).build();
}
```

then adding to the `Notification.Builder`:

```
Notification noti = getNotificationBuilder(time, description)
            .addAction(getResetAction())
            .addAction(getFinishAction())
            .addAction(getStartAction())
            .setStyle(new Notification.MediaStyle().
                    setShowActionsInCompactView(0, 1, 2))
            .build();
    notificationManager.notify(MEDITATION_NOTIFICATION_ID, noti);
```

The `finish` icon is my own but the others are all from the framework so I don't understand why they aren't sharp. This is built with `compileSdkVersion 27` Oreo and running on Nexus 5X running 8.1.0.

Comment: have you been able to find an answer to this? I am dealing with the same issue since I have been trying to run my Android 2.2 app on an Android 8.1 smartphone.