# How to fix distorted R.drawable icons when updating app from API 8 to API 26+

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library, android-drawable, android-api-levels

I am trying to revive and revise a 10+ years old app (Android 2.2, 4.1) that was displaying and functioning fine back then but now, when installed on an Android 8.1 device, it exhibits the following odd visual issue:

On API 8/16 it displays [R.drawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.drawable) icons/buttons as intended:

[image]

But on API 26/29 it displays the same this way (unintended):

[image]

The main.xml section responsible for displaying this is:

```
        <!-- horizontal row of 3 buttons (prev, pause/play, next) -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/prev_pauseplay_next_buttons"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <com.susu.mylib.core.MyButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_prev"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_media_previous"
        />
    
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_pause_or_play_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <com.susu.mylib.core.MyButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_pause"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:drawable/ic_media_pause"
            android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="36dp"
            />
        <com.susu.mylib.core.MyButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_play"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:drawable/ic_media_play"
            android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="36dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout> <!-- end ll_pause_or_play_button -->
    
        <com.susu.mylib.core.MyButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_next"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:drawable/ic_media_next"
            />
</LinearLayout> <!-- end prev_pauseplay_next_buttons -->
```

Any idea why is this happening and how to fix this?

Also, which Android SDK library or jar contains these images?

Comment: use vector images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
<ImageView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:scaleType="centerCrop"
/>
```

instead of background

or wrap your old drawables into:

***res/drawable/wrapped_ic_media_pause.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@android:drawable/ic_media_pause"
        android:gravity="center"
        height="24dp"
        width="24dp"
        />
</layer-list>
```

and then in your xml use `@drawable/wrapped_ic_media_pause` instead of `@android:drawable/ic_media_pause`

specify height and width if needed (otherwise icon might be tiny)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed solutions. I see no reference to the actual R.drawable "stock items" (e.g ic_media_pause, ic_media_play). Where do these fit in your solutions? If you could use my posted XML to illustrate how your solutions fits into it (especially the first one), this would be super.

Comment: I have updated my answer so it showcases how you can use `@android:drawable/ic_media_pause` as background and have it centered instead of having it stretched. I have also updated the width and height to be 24dp as it is very likely to be the value you want.

Comment: Thank you @RadekJ. This works now like a charm. Your guess regarding 24p is correct. BTW, I think that this also answers a 4+ year old question that went unanswed: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51963077/2597758